# How would one geocode historical US census records?

Tags: geocoding, census

I want to geocode census records from the U.S.  Here is one [example from 1870](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/1870_census_Lindauer_Weber_02.gif).  This particular census page is from the 6th election district, 8th ward of New York County.  Here's one from the [1910 Census](http://www.usgwarchives.org/pa/cameron/census/1910/002-05a.gif).  This one mentions the county, township, supervisor district, and enumeration district.

I can geocode the county, state.  I'm wondering if there are any resources which include latitude/longitude for districts, wards, supervisor districts, and enumeration districts from the past to help me geocode census records.  I did find [NHGIS](http://www.nhgis.org/), but their data is quite sparse for anything more fine grained than the county level before 1940.

Comment: Try http://www.nhgis.org/project-information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

County Level (some states go back to 1776)

http://publications.newberry.org/ahcbp/
(in lat/lng)

you can use this to attach census data (where available) to the county polygons (you maybe doing this already)

But downloaded the GIS Data and there is a wealth of facts on changes etc. with dates and sources.
A worthy start.

Finding GIS (geocoder. address data is going to be a challenge) pre 1990 is a big task.
But hopefully with a lot of research and clues.

You will find data sporadic.

Best of luck with the project.

Answer (score 0):

The [Urban Transition Historical GIS Project](https://s4.ad.brown.edu/Projects/UTP2/ncities.htm) at Brown has GIS maps for the largest cities in the country for the 1880–1940 censuses (excluding 1890 of course).

> The long-term goal of the Urban Transition HGIS project is to provide historically accurate GIS maps and geocoded data for many U.S. cities in the whole period 1880-1940.

This includes Manhattan and Brooklyn. The data is freely downloadable, although it comes with license restrictions for commercial use.